# Google Api create event without accepting it

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am using Google API to create an appointment calendar and I want to add events to the Calendar without accepting it. So to be specific -

a. I have a user who manages Appointments for a company
b. The company has gmail account / google calendar account
c. So, when another user(user2) selects a date and submits an appointment request
d. I add the event to the gmail account using the Google APi create event

But I am not sure if the created event is automatically accepted or if the gmail user has to explicitly accept it. I couldn't find information in the Google API documentation. Does someone have pointers?

Kishan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inserted an event and then found that it needs to be explicitly accepted in the Calendar as a response to notification. So, I guess that answers my above question.